# Properties of linear maps: Injectivity, invertibility and surjectivity in dependence of vectorspace dimensions

Tags: linear-algebra

Given is a linear map f from V to W, whereby V has dimension n and W has dimension m.

Now given n > m, can the map be injective,surjective or invertible?
And what about the same questions, given that m > n?

My thoughts so far:

- Invertibility should be possible in the second case, if we think of the map e.g. as a quadratic matrix which maps from the V to a subspace of W, but not in the first case (the matrix would not be quadratic.
- Injectivity  could be possible in the second case - else basically the a vector in W must have two pre-images
- Surjectivity should be possible in the first case - the image of a linear map can not have a bigger dimensionaly than the space V

Is this correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint:

All of the possibilities would be governed by the [rank-nullity theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rank%E2%80%93nullity_theorem):

For your linear map $f$, $$\dim (V)-\dim(\ker(f))=\dim(Im(F))\leq \dim( W)$$

This helps you to rule out impossible cases using dimension.

Keep in mind that $f$ is injective iff $\dim(\ker(f))=0$ and $f$ is surjective iff $\dim(Im(f))=\dim(W)$.

Comment: ...I see, and as far as I know the map is injective <=> kernel has dimension zero

Comment: @TestGuest That's true, and it's surjective $\iff \dim(Im(f))=\dim(W)$.

Answer (score 0):

You're incorrect about invertibility in the usual sense of the word.

Generally, for $f$ to be invertible, there needs to be a map $g \DeclareMathOperator{\id}{id}$ such that $f \circ g$ and $g \circ f$ are both the identity map.

In order for a $g$ to exist such that $g \circ f =\id_V$, $f$ would need to be injective. In order for a $g$ to exist such that $f \circ g = \id_W$, $f$ would need to be surjective.  Since $f$ can only be injective and surjective when $m=n$, your $f$ is never "invertible".

Comment: Can you expand on why it is not possible that $f$ is injective and surjective if $m \neq n$?

Comment: @philmcole it's just the [pigeonhole principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pigeonhole_principle)